# Met strange error when using pinvoke to call ReadFile in background thread

Tags: pinvoke

What I am doing is writing a WPF application to work with our device. The application writes some commands to the device and reads command's response from it. I got pinvoke declarations from pinvoke.net website for CreateFile, WriteFile, ReadFile, etc.

I made a function doing following things, CreateFile(with flag FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED
) to open device, WriteFile to send command, ReadFile to read response, WaitForSingleObject and GetOverlappedResult to capture timeout exception if device doesn't respond, and CloseHandle to close device.

This function always worked fine if I called it in UI thread. But I wanted to call it in background thread to keep UI active. So I created a thread in Window_Loaded method(Work is my function's name).

```
t = new Thread(Work);
t.Start();
```

Then ReadFile, WaitForSingleObject and GetOverlappedResult group may met error, these three functions returned success and GetOverlappedResult could capture correct read length returned from device. But no actual data read from device filled in the byte array buffer passed to ReadFile function. The failure rate was about 50%.

If I waited thread t to finish, then it always worked fine again.

```
t = new Thread(Work);
t.Start();
t.join();
```

Of cause UI would also hang in this situation.

I searched this problem but no exact same question was found. I tried to set background thread's apartment state to STA or MTA explicitly, but it didn't work.

```
t = new Thread(Work);
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

It really confuses me. Please help me if you have any idea. Thank you for  your reading.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the root cause. But I bypassed it by rewriting read process in C++ function and calling my C++ function with pInvoke.